# How to compare arrays values the array should contains particular digit in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am working with asp.net and jQuery, I am somewhat new at jQuery. I need to compare the arrays.

For example I have two arrays like this:

```
  containValues=[1,2];
  SelectedValues=[1,3,4,5];
```

I need to check means compare the arrays values my condition is the 'containValues' array values should contains in  the SelectedValues

```
   [1,2]==[1,3,4,5,2] now it should return true 
   [1,2]==[1,3,4,5] now it should return false
```

This should my output. I have tried, but it always returns false. What am I doing wrong?

```
 function containsAll(containValues, SelectedValues) {
        alert(containValues);
        alert(SelectedValues);
        var i = containValues.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (containValues[i] === SelectedValues)
             alert('matched'); ;
        }
        alert('not matched');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
function containsAll(containValues, selectedValues) { 
   if (containValues.Length > selectedValues.Length) { 
      return false;
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < containValues.length; i++) { 
       if (selectedValues.indexOf(containValues[i]) < 0) { 
           return false;
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Havent put too much thought into it though so test it carefuly.

Answer (score 0):

On this line you are comparing a single element in containValues to the entire SelectedValues array:

```
if (containValues[i] === SelectedValues)
```

instead, you want to make sure every element in SelectedValues is in containValues.  Try this:

```
function containsAll(containValues, SelectedValues) {

    alert(containValues);
    alert(SelectedValues);

    for(i = 0; i < containValues.length; i++){
        if (SelectedValues.indexOf(containValues[i]) === -1){
            alert('not matched');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('matched');
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Also, there is no jQuery at all here.  This is pure javascript.

Comment: Yup I flipped contain values and selected values.  Let me fix.

Comment: OK, fixed it.  You should be looping over the elements in containValues.  Each of them should have an index in SelectedValues.  If so, it returns true, otherwise false.

Comment: There was a typo BTW.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function isInArray(arr) {
    var match = [1, 2];
    var getArray = arr;

    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(match[i], getArray) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
alert(isInArray([1, 3, 4, 5, 2]));
alert(isInArray([1, 3, 4, 5]))
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/694W9/8/)

Comment: @Sadda-shutu . check my demo  any doubt ask me ..sorry it is too late

Comment: thnks for reply Bala let me check